# Binding of `this` in a setTimeout() callback in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, inside a callback passed to `setTimeout()`, `this` seems to be bound to the `timeoutObject` returned by `setTimeout()` itself (both in strict mode and in non strict mode!):

```
var timeoutObject = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(this === timeoutObject); // true
}, 0);

var timeoutObject = setTimeout(function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log(this === timeoutObject); // true
}, 0);
```

This is not the case in the browser, where `this` is bound (as I would expect) to the global object `window` (or is `undefined`, in strict mode).

The documentation doesn't say anything about this non-standard behaviour.

Why is this?

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: I pointed out what I think is wrong with that. I would expect `this` to be bound to the global object, like in any other callback. All browsers bind `this` to the global object, whereas Node.js doesn't.

Comment: Hm, node is not a browser and doesn't need to repeat the mistakes of old that were [codified with HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout). Using the global object is pretty much despised in node, so why call the callback on it? The respective timer (that is not a number, but has methods of its own) makes much more sense.

Comment: Node is not a browser indeed, but it's not another implementation of ECMAScript — it uses the JavaScript engine of a popular browser. I think that the answer is that since `setTimeout()` is not in the ECMAScript specification, Node.js has its own implementation that is different from the way it is implemented in all the browsers.

Comment: @kYuZz Exactly. `setTimeout` is defined by W3C/WHATWG, not ECMAScript. Node.js is an implementation of ECMAScript, but is not a browser.

Comment: Is the question "why is this?", or are you having concrete problems with it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one discussion [`` this` binding incorrect for `setTimeouf(..)` and `setInterval(..) ``](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7931). Which explains the question, there was even an attempt to fix it which was not accepted.

Here are some ideas as below

> `setTimeout` binds the timer object to "this" object in the callback.
>   First of all, in most cases, the execution environment in Node is a "module", so when
>
> ```
> var k=2;
> exports.k=3;
> console.log(k);//2
> console.log(this.k);//3
> ```
>
> This is the difference between browser and node. Making reference to "window" object in browser is easy becasuse it is a global object. But in Node, setTimeout/setInterval does no way to get the "exports" object nor the execution environment of the module.

---

> Regardless, there are advantages to the current way set*() works (though, granted it is undocumented but it is being used in the wild). For example:
>
> ```
> setInterval(function() {
>   if (/* <condition> */)
>     this.unref();
>   // do more stuff
> }, /* <n> */);
> ```

Comment: The discussion in the issue explains the question, there was even an [attempt to fix it](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/pull/7955) which was not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs is not browser. "Standards" what you are talking about are for browsers. Read the docs:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout

To implement these 2 timing functions "this" should be binded to window object (not available in Nodejs) or worker object (not available in nodejs).

Nodejs has it's own global object, that might be good target in this case, but I think it's better to have this binded to this function, not some global object. Seems like developers from Nodejs thinks that way too.

It's not against the "standards" because standards has nothing about such environment, where window, navigation, location objects are not present.